# When to use Ask pattern in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

I'm started to learn Akka and in many official examples I see that `request-response` implemented using `tell` pattern. I.e. after worker made his work he sends result as new message back to sender. For example in [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html) Pi approximation official tutorial shown how to design application where Master sends some work to workers and then awaits for results as another message.

Master code:

```
def receive = {
  case Calculate ⇒
    for (i ← 0 until nrOfMessages) workerRouter ! Work(i * nrOfElements, nrOfElements)
  case Result(value) ⇒
    pi += value
    nrOfResults += 1
    if (nrOfResults == nrOfMessages) {
      // Send the result to the listener
      listener ! PiApproximation(pi, duration = (System.currentTimeMillis - start).millis)
      // Stops this actor and all its supervised children
      context.stop(self)
    }
}
```

Worker code:

```
 def receive = {
    case Work(start, nrOfElements) ⇒
      sender ! Result(calculatePiFor(start, nrOfElements)) // perform the work
  }
```

But I'm wondering why this example didn't use ask pattern? What is wrong with using ask pattern here?

If it's ok to use ask pattern here, then I have another question: how I can stop all worker actors after work is done?

1. Should my worker actors send `PoisonPill` message to themselves?
2. Or should Master actor `Broadcast(PoisonPill)`?
3. Or there some another more elegant way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ask` is useful when integrating actors with `Future` APIs, but they do introduce some overhead. Further, `Future` completions do not come through an actor's mailbox and are scheduled on a thread separate from the one used by the mailbox, meaning that receiving a future completion inside an actor introduces the need for doing multi-thread coordination.

Meanwhile, if you use `tell` to send to a worker and have it `tell` the `sender` in response, the communication will always flow properly through the mailbox channel.

Additionally, it is much easier to discern the inputs an actor deals with if they all come in via `receive` rather than some coming in via `receive` and other's as completions of `ask` messages.

To address you `PoisonPill` questions, the answer is likely *depends*. You might opt for a *worker-per-message* approach in which case the worker should kill itself. If instead you use a worker pool, you could make the supervisor responsible for scaling that pool up and down, having it send the `PoisonPill` or have workers time out on idleness, once again killing themselves.

Comment: I agree on all points and add one more: with asking you need to worry about timeouts. Asking is usually used when you want one specific reply within a time frame and you want to choose what to do in case of failure for this one specific message.